# How do I remove quotes from a string?

Tags: php, quotes

```
$string = "my text has \"double quotes\" and 'single quotes'";
```

How to remove all types of quotes (different languages) from `$string`?

Comment: $string has no quotes in it you do realize this?

Comment: what about quotes represented as htmlentities or urlencoded?

Comment: Are you talking about natural-language quotes (for example, „) or about programming-language quotes (such as `/*...*/`)?

Comment: @Chris - does now ! :)

Comment: If you're just removing them from the start and end, then `trim($str, "\"\'")`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
str_replace('"', "", $string);
str_replace("'", "", $string);
```

I assume you mean quotation marks?

Otherwise, go for some regex, this will work for html quotes for example:

```
preg_replace("/<!--.*?-->/", "", $string);
```

C-style quotes:

```
preg_replace("/\/\/.*?\n/", "\n", $string);
```

CSS-style quotes:

```
preg_replace("/\/*.*?\*\//", "", $string);
```

bash-style quotes:

```
preg-replace("/#.*?\n/", "\n", $string);
```

Etc etc...

Comment: It is impossible to parse HTML with regular expressions properly. Never try to do that.

Comment: I agree, but it's also impossible to parse **every** programming language properly...

Comment: str_replace accepts arrays as well, so str_replace(array('"', "'"), '', $string) will also work.  Btw, are you saying that HTML is a programming language? ;-)

Comment: No of course not but it's still impossible to handle comments from every programming language ;)

Comment: All your regular expressions are broken. You did not specify delimiters and escaping has been omitted as well.

Comment: These were meant as examples; Yes, preg functions require delimiters but they are not part of the regular expression, and the delimiters cause incorrect reading of the forward slashes.

Comment: @J V: They are not part of the regular expressions, but they are part of your examples. And your examples do not work without delimiters. @Gumbo: Thats right.

Comment: Parsing HTML can give cancer. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454
for more details

Answer (score 13):

You can do the same in one line:

```
str_replace(['"',"'"], "", $text)
```