# php form handling input value post self some characters error

Tags: php, forms

i post data into form action to php self some characters make errors. This charactor are `"` or `\` if u put `"` input name return into `\` how to fix it

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <label for="name"></label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value='<? print htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>' />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  <? print htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: do you really have _short tags_ on?

Comment: Read up on XSS and how to prevent it

Comment: isnt the "short tag" format suppose to be `<?= $var ?>` rather than `<? echo $var ?>`?

Comment: @CodeGodie no it isn't. Short echo syntax and short open tags are two somewhat different things.

Comment: Gotcha. needed to know the difference

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228282/how-do-i-remove-quotes-from-a-string I guess you have a quote problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what the problem is but I think you are getting errors when returning special characters into an input field. If so try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php you will need to convert the special characters into html entities so the data isnt read as code which will cause issues.
I have just tested this by changing the `message` `input` to `<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); ?>` and the characters are displaying as normal.
Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); ?>" />
            <br />
            <label for="message"></label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        echoed (<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); ?>);
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP most likely wants `htmlspecialchars` instead

Comment: but wont `htmlentities` convert all characters so it gives a better result as oppose to `htmlspecialchars` that only converts certain characters, unless im reading the docs wrong?

Comment: Yes, but in 99.9% of the cases there is no need to convert all characters making the document needlessly heavy :-)

Comment: Ah thats a good point. So `htmlspecialchars` in this case would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes correct. Just pass the correct encoding and most likely the `ENT_QUOTES` flag and OP should be fine :-)

Comment: name input give `look "` then the result is `look \"` still no get solution by `htmlentities`  and `htmlspecialchars` @Anthony Broadbent

Comment: @Henok is there any more code that you havent shown? It looks like the data from the input field is being escaped and that would be why you are getting the \" when you use just ". I have made an example here: http://seafreshdirect.com/ant/php/entities.php and it works as expected.

Comment: @Anthony Broadbent can u paste code here or Edit my question

Comment: @Henok Ive updated my answer with the code I used. If this doesn't work then there may be issues with your PHP configuration.