# how do i replace a character in my array with another character?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array - the output of my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["-"] => 7
    ["FR"] => 3
)
```

and i want to replace the "-" with "other"

so it should look like this at the end:

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["other"] => 7
    ["FR"] => 3
)
```

could someone help me with this? str_replace havent worked with me...
and if you could i want to have the "other" part of the array at the bottom - 
like this:

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["FR"] => 3
    ["other"] => 7
)
```

thanks :)

current code:

```
 $array_land = explode("\n", $land_exec_result);
 $count_land = array_count_values($array_land);
        arsort($count_land);
        $arr['other'] = $count_land["-"];
        unset($count_land["-"]);
```

but this havent worked for me :/

Comment: damn.. need to go offline now.. but i will response to anyone who tries to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple like that:

```
$array["other"] = $array["-"];
unset($array["-"]);
```

At the end, the array will be like this:

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["FR"] => 3
    ["other"] => 7
)
```

Comment: i edited my question :) this in your answer havent worked for me :/

Comment: php just gives me an: Undefined index: - ( so php doesnt find the "-" character )

Comment: Are you sure the array $count_land have the "-" index? If you print_r the $count_land what will be the output?

Comment: what you see in my question is the output of $count_land :)

Comment: Have you tried escape the "-"? Like "\-"?

Comment: yes i did but it still says undefined index :o what really curious is.. i cant explain why php say that "-" is an undefined index

Comment: Let me try here, just a sec.

Comment: Man, here works like a charm. Lets try something. Make a foreach like this:

`foreach($count_land as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
}`

Whats the value printed when the foreach pass on "-"? It's really one character?

Comment: this gives me a : string(4) ""US"" string(4) ""DE"" string(4) ""BR"" string(3) ""-"" string(4) ""FR"" as an output

Comment: Did you  get it? The string are quoted, all of them. So you may need to remove the quotes or do this: `$count_land['"-"']`

I think the better way is remove the quotes, look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228282/how-do-i-remove-quotes-from-a-string

Comment: yes i got it :) without var dump i havent seen that there were more characters as i thought :p now it works perfekt :) thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr['other'] = $arr['-'];
unset($arr['-']);
```

The first command stores the value of your `$arr['-']` element in a new element named `$arr['other']`. When you create a new element this way for an array with named indexes the new element will automatically be placed at the end of the array.

The second command removes the `$arr['-']` element from the array.
The result will be:

```
Array
(
    ["US"] => 186
    ["DE"] => 44
    ["BR"] => 15
    ["FR"] => 3
    ["other"] => 7
)
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer. SO doesn't exist to just answer questions but teach people how to code.

Comment: hello, sorry that i havent replied earlyer... thanks for the answer but it didnt worked with me :o i updated my question so may we can fight a solution :)

Comment: php just gave me an: Undefined index: - ( so php doesnt find the "-" character )